# Can't find memory field in structLogs field in debug_traceTransaction RPC Call

Tags: go-ethereum, memory, internal-transactions, stack

I'm trying to index internal eth transactions transactions of the Ethereum blockchain and as it is not present in the logs, the way is to replay the transaction with debug_tracetransaction so I can rebuild the transaction and see the internal eth transfers.

I only want to index new transactions so I should be able to do it without a full archive node, as debug_tracetransaction is available for the latest 128 blocks.

As it says in the documentation I have a field structLogs with all the steps of the transaction.

I do have the stack field but not the memory one.

I'm running a node with geth 1.10.17-stable-25c9b49f
with snap synced with the following command :

```
geth --http --http.addr 0.0.0.0 --http.api eth,web3,debug,txpool,net,admin,debug --ws --ws.api eth,web3,debug,txpool,net,admin,debug  --ws.origins localhost --syncmode snap --datadir /mnt/md1 --gcmode archive
```

I'm requesting the node to give me the debugged transaction with following command

```
curl --data '{"method":"debug_traceTransaction","params":["0xd3ba2428f24ce620da5d6c2401f5f1c17cf88d31a0bd8731f2a64fd6debbb487", {"disableStack": false, "disableMemory": false, "disableStorage": false}],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545
```

This is an example of the step i'm getting :

```
{"pc":876,"op":"JUMPI","gas":38785,"gasCost":10,"depth":1,"stack":["0x38ed1739","0x100","0x772","0x772","0x7b2","0x120","0x60","0x60","0x7b2","0x120","0x40","0x0","0x37c"]}
```

The documentation :
https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/ns-debug#debug_tracetransaction

If someone has any idea of what I should do to get the memory field without running an archive node from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

In your RPC request, you are specifying `disableMemory: false`. However, according to these docs https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/ns-debug#debug_tracetransaction, the option key is `enableMemory` and **not** `disableMemory`.

To have memory included in the output for `debug_traceTransaction`, try using `enableMemory: true`.